# Programmable Media Playback for Raspberry PI

Tags: media-player, raspberry-pi, remote-control

I am looking for a solution to playback media (1080p Video, Audio) using a Raspberry PI 4, which is controllable (Play/Pause, Media Selection, Playback Start Position, Volume, Ideally "dimmer"/ Video-Brightness) using a network control protocol, ideally ArtNET or REST.

It's important for me, that it can playback the following formats:

- Video e.g. (h264)
- Audio (ideally mp3 or wav)
- images

I want to use this for Streaming using an ATEM Switcher or for Live Productions and showing media on a projector or TV on Stage in a Play, so there should not be any on screen display. Ideally, there would be a way to fade out the image using network controls (e.g. change the opacity against a black background). If it could do layered stuff, resizing and repositioning, it would be even more awesome (e.g. display a Transparent PNG with a Logo on top, that resizes from a large centered logo to a smaller bug in the corner).

Volume, Brightness, (+ Size and X/Y Coordinates if possible) should be "fadeable".

and if two instances on two pis would run synchronous, it would be awesome, but not a hard requirement (e.g. one TV left and right on stage, which show the logo animation and then one fades to the name of the speaker and the other to a video with audio and a third one connected to the audio mixer, which only plays the audio of the video)

Is there any software that does this on a Rasperry PI using Linux (or comparably small and inexpensive hardware using Linux)?

Some notes for clarification:

- the projector will be directly connected to the Raspberry Pi
- media should be stored on that Raspberry or a flashdrive directly connected to it (not cast to it)
- media playback shall be controlled over the network via REST or ARTNET or programmable Protocol which can be mapped to ArtNET (without ANY OSD overlays on the output)
- network remote control needs to be able to change volume, start (at current position)/pause/rewind, ideally fade video brightness

Comment: @Izzy I've added a last point, then it's fine.

Comment: Wonderful! Best luck then! I'm now cleaning up comments then.